# When I debug my project by Android studio, my phone's screen will be white before running for a long time

Tags: android, android-studio

This is the log of console:

```
03/23 14:46:58: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -p com.romens.yjk.health.njxszk /Users/bsn/project/YJKHealthForAndroid的副本 2/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/channel_nj_xszk/debug/slices/slice_7.apk /Users/bsn/project/YJKHealthForAndroid的副本 2/app/build/outputs/apk/app-channel_nj_xszk-debug_v1.16.0_c170321.apk 
Split APKs installed
$ adb shell am startservice com.romens.yjk.health.njxszk/com.android.tools.fd.runtime.InstantRunService
$ adb shell am start -n "com.romens.yjk.health.njxszk/com.romens.yjk.health.njxszk.ui.activity.IntroActivityNew" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Connecting to com.romens.yjk.health.njxszk
Now Launching Native Debug Session
Starting LLDB server: /data/data/com.romens.yjk.health.njxszk/lldb/bin/start_lldb_server.sh /data/data/com.romens.yjk.health.njxszk/lldb unix-abstract /data/data/com.romens.yjk.health.njxszk/lldb/tmp platform-1490251628644.sock "lldb process:gdb-remote packets"
$ adb shell cat /data/local/tmp/lldb-server | run-as com.romens.yjk.health.njxszk sh -c 'cat > /data/data/com.romens.yjk.health.njxszk/lldb/bin/lldb-server && chmod 700 /data/data/com.romens.yjk.health.njxszk/lldb/bin/lldb-server'
$ adb shell cat /data/local/tmp/start_lldb_server.sh | run-as com.romens.yjk.health.njxszk sh -c 'cat > /data/data/com.romens.yjk.health.njxszk/lldb/bin/start_lldb_server.sh && chmod 700 /data/data/com.romens.yjk.health.njxszk/lldb/bin/start_lldb_server.sh'
Debugger attached to process 11874
```

I found when I debug,"app-java" appear and many .so files will be loaded. [image: app-java]
And I change another project and debug it, this problem will not happen. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Disable your insta run from settings menu and test it, I was experiencing same issue i disabled insta run and it worked for me. You can find this setting under Build, Execution, Deplyoment.

Comment: My English is poor. Can you elaborate on it?  Thanks.

Comment: After you've disabled Instant Run, clean your app by Build->clean from menu

Comment: I have did this, but it did'n work.  File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Instant Run,  disable Instant Run to hot... ?  Is this right?

Comment: Yes that's right. If it's still persist, then the problem lies in your code.

Comment: Do you know the problem may be what?

Comment: maybe some code doing a heavy process in your main Activity.

Comment: I found when I debug, many .so files will be loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I used this way solved my problem](http://blog.csdn.net/qq_36255612/article/details/53502441)

[image: select Edit Configurations]
[image: select Java]
Then apply.

Answer (score 1):

Check that is your instant run is enable or not just go to :

File->setting->Build,Execution,Deployment -> instant run - > disable it.

Re-build and run your project it will fix .THanks:)